# How to secure an existing Asp.Net project with ADFS

Tags: single-sign-on, forms-authentication, adfs, adfs2.0

I have a big project in asp.net and I want to embed ADFS in it for authentication purpose.

Please suggest some links.

Thanks

Comment: I have created a relying party trust from a federationmetadata file. I want to know about next steps. What ADFS APIs I need to use inside my code.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify:

You don't embed ADFS in an ASP.NET application. You add WIF or OWIN to the application and bind this with ADFS which sits on a Windows server. The latest version is ADFS 3.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

[How To: Build Claims-Aware ASP.NET Web Forms Application Using WIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh987037(v=vs.110).aspx)

[WS-Federation in Microsoft OWIN Components–a quick start](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/20/ws-federation-in-microsoft-owin-componentsa-quick-start/)

OWIN is the newer technology.

And then you bind your application to ADFS.

[Building a test claims-aware ASP.NET application and integrating it with ADFS 2.0 Security Token Service (STS)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alextch/archive/2011/06/27/building-a-test-claims-aware-asp-net-application-and-integrating-it-with-adfs-2-0-security-token-service-sts.aspx)